# node-inspector/v8-profiler not starting profiling or creating v8 log file

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I have the following nodejs code

```
var profiler = require("v8-profiler");

profiler.startProfiling("FooBar");

doSomethingAsync(function() {
  profiler.stopProfiling("FooBar");
});
```

I run this:

```
$ time node --prof --prof_lazy test/performance/performance-test.js
```

However I don't get a v8.log file.

I did have some issues installing the v8-profiler package related to [this issue with node-profiler](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler/issues/16).  I use MacPorts, and g++ defaults to /opt/local/bin/g++ (I use the nodejs package provided from MacPorts as well)  I managed to get around the -arch error by using g++ that comes with XCode

```
$ CXX="xcrun g++" npm install v8-profiler
```

It might be a red herring, but it's worth mentioning incase the resulting v8-profiler binary objects doesn't work with my nodejs install.

```
$ node --version
v0.10.22

$ npm --version
1.3.15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `--log` option if you want to get a v8.log file.

```
$ node --prof --prof_lazy --log test/performance/performance-test.js
```

However, when you use v8-profiler, the log file does not contain profiling data. I guess it is because `profiler.stopProfiling()` returns the profiling data to the caller. See the example in project's [README](https://github.com/node-inspector/v8-profiler):

```
profiler.startProfiling([name])                   //begin cpu profiling
var cpuProfile = profiler.stopProfiling([name])   //finish cpu profiling
```

There is another module that allows you to manually start/stop the profiler, while writing the profiling data to v8.log: [node-profiler](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler). I did not manage to get it compiled with Node v0.8 nor v0.10, you may want to fill an issue in the project's issue tracker.

Comment: I obviously had a brain fart @miroslav-bajtos when reading the README as I didn't make the connection that the profiling data is returned from stopProfiling.  If I wanted to examine the data is there an example of dumping the result to a file, or loading it up in node-inspector?

I tried using node-profiler but it doesn't like the output of Node v0.10, I'll raise an issue.

Comment: I've been using https://github.com/sidorares/node-tick to process the v8.log as the nprof tool provided by node-profiler doesn't process v0.10 output.

Comment: I don't know. You can try out bugger, it allows you to start/stop/inspect profiler from the devtools GUI.